extended disk in cfdisk but it will not grow in df -h
i have a VM running ubuntu and extended a disk to 6Tb, i saw the extra space in the cfdisk command and resized it to the max (6t)

it shows up as 6t in fdisk as well

but in df -h it will not grow in size and shows up as 223GB

im not fluent with linux so this is all new, i have tried growpart, resize2fs but none of them make this disk show up as 6t in df -h..
any direction appreciated please!!

Please don't post images of text.

What is the output of sudo file -skr /dev/sdb1?

Please replace the images with formatted text (use the {} button to format as code)
